# Do I have to pay the permanency for the instantaneous versions of create demiplane?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Pathfinder's [Create Demiplane](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateMagic/spells/createDemiplane.html) can be cast to increase the demiplane's size, or to add/remove traits.

> You can use this spell to expand a demiplane you created with create lesser demiplane (you do not need to create an entirely new plane using this spell), in which case it has a duration of 1 day/level. Alternatively, when cast within your demiplane, you may add (or remove) one of the following features to your demiplane with each casting of the spell, in which case it has an instantaneous duration.

And it requires permanency:

> You can make this spell permanent with the permanency spell, at a cost of 20,000 gp. If you have cast create demiplane multiple times to enlarge the demiplane, each casting's area requires its own permanency spell.

But requiring permanency on an instantaneous effect is rather strange, because next turn there is no effect to make permanent, it is already gone.

I'm rather new to PF, so do I need to pay the permanency for the traits version of the spell, or just for the increasing in size?

Answer (score 6):

From the description:

> You can use this spell to expand a demiplane you created with create lesser demiplane [...], in which case it has a duration of 1 day/level. Alternatively, when cast within your demiplane, you may add (or remove) one of the following features to your demiplane with each casting of the spell, in which case it has an instantaneous duration.

Adding permanency only works on size increases. The instantaneous use of adding features can't (and don't need to) benefit from permanency.

Answer (score 2):

The way I'm reading that the duration is only Instantaneous if you are modifying an existing demiplane (for example by adding a dominant elemental trait).
In such cases the existing demiplane's duration are not affected and any permanency effects applied to the original plane will continue as normal.

Any demiplane you want to make permanent costs money according to the permanency rules you quoted, including size increases, but not feature changes.